# How to create a button for dynamically created file download?

Tags: vaadin, hilla

To provide dynamically created file download button in Vaadin, we usually create a Button with Anchor wrapper around and use StreamResource to return file data to browser as file download. How to accomplish that in Hilla? I can't see  a Anchor element available in view? I was looking for Vaadin Fusion example but no luck.

**Edit 1:** Here is a screenshot when accessing SpringBoot controller URL. Hila is actually responding ...
[image]

Comment: You don't need that. You can simply use a standard <a href="">

Comment: I just wondered if here is a way how do it using '@Endpoint' bean directly instead of exposing a '@Controller' with specific URL.

Comment: You should use a Controller because you want to set the Produces attribute to the content type you created. That's not possible with Endpoint

Comment: I'm back on track now. Trying with SpringBoot controller but actually Hilla maps on my SpringBoot controller URL. So when I call a URL assigned to controller, Hilla is responding to that. Any hint for some configuration option here? I assume some Servlet configuration is needed here ...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your the problem and added my example as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a REST Controller and use a standard `<a href="...">` to download the file.

Here is an example how this would look to download a PDF:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/file")
public class FileController {

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public byte[] get(String parameter) {
        // return the file
    }
}
```

Comment: I'v done in very the same way. But when accessing through '/api/file' I can see Hilla serves this URL, not SpringBoot.

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example? And which Hilla Version are you using?

Comment: I was running Hilla 1.1.4. Updated my pom to version 1.1.7 and it works as expected. Thanks for a hint!